# Thread-safe Global Resource in Android with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android apps and the activity lifecyle seems to force reliance on globals. (Even with Dagger there are stateful, global Dagger objects that perform dependency injection.)

I'd like to make a globally available mode object called `GlobalMode`. The mode should be changeable at runtime. This is what I have so far:

```
interface Mode {
    fun doSomething(a: Int);
}

class NormalMode : Mode {
    override fun doSomething(a: Int) {
        // ...
    }
}

class DebugMode : Mode {
    override fun doSomething(a: Int) {
        // ...
    }
}

object GlobalMode : Mode {

    private var mode: Mode? = null;

    private fun getMode() : Mode {
        if (this.mode == null) {
            this.mode = NormalMode();
        }
        return this.mode!!;
    }

    fun setMode(mode: Mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    override fun doSomething(a: Int) {
        this.getMode().doSomething(a = a);
    }

}
```

The Kotlin `object` declaration is great for making the global object. It definitely seems better than the singleton pattern in Java. I love how I can declare the global object to implement the `Mode` interface.

What I don't know how to do is make the following part thread safe. If instantiation of `NormalMode` is expensive, two threads could cause the expensive instantiation as there is no synchornization inside the `null` check.

```
        if (this.mode == null) {
            this.mode = NormalMode();
        }
```

I thought about doing something like this because apparently `lazy` initialization is thread safe.

```
object GlobalMode : Mode {

    private var mode: Mode? = null;

    private val defaultMode: Mode by lazy {
        NormalMode();
    }

    private fun getMode() : Mode {
        if (this.mode == null) {
            this.mode = this.defaultMode;
        }
        return this.mode!!;
    }

    // ...

}
```

The problem with this `lazy` approach is that once `defaultMode` has been assigned, it is permanent. If something happens at runtime to change the mode for the rest of the applications lifetime, `defaultMode` still holds a strong reference to the `NormalMode` object which means that object can never be garbage collected. It will never be used again but it can never be garbage collected.

How can I make the following part thread safe in a better way?

```
        if (this.mode == null) {
            this.mode = NormalMode();
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Java, you can make the method synchronized:

```
@Synchronized private fun getMode() : Mode {
    if (this.mode == null) {
        this.mode = this.defaultMode;
    }
    return this.mode!!;
}
```